# Scroll down change website route

Tags: javascript, html, web

I was browsing quartz earlier today and noticed something interesting. When you scroll down between one article to the next article the website route changes as you are scrolling. What technology/javascript package is driving this?

Ex http://qz.com/305715/the-quartz-chart-of-the-year-short-list-is-here/

Comment: I'd say they load the pages content via ajax while you are scrolling and change the url with javascript

Answer (score 0):

They are using some kind of an infinite scroll (lots of libraries, just google it), and some kind of a routing library/plugin (like Backbone.Router). The routing lib uses History API in newer browsers or hash-based URL fragments in older ones.

Basically they wait for you to scroll to the end of the article, which fires an event. After that the infinity scroll loads another article via AJAX and sets the new route via the routing lib.

Answer (score 0):

My friend asked me the same. So I made a plugin for it. I think this is what you want.

https://github.com/wataruoguchi/clever-infinite-scroll

This is the process of how to change the URL using infinite scrolling.

1. Watching scroll event. When scrolling hit the bottom of the page,
   Ajax calls next content. The link refers next content is removed.
   It's pretty basic of infinite scroll.
2. When next content loaded, it implements hidden span tags contain URL string and page title string of the content. Watching scroll event.
3. When the content is seen according to the scroll position, change the URL by history.pushState(). URL and title both strings are gotten from hidden span elements.
4. At the same timing, it changes the page title as well.